# how do i store android json array in php databse?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am developing an android application to store and invite user
contacts on the server.

*the array I am having from android is JSON format.*

```
$a='[
      {"phone":"(785) 583-7086","name":"Website 22-2-16"},
      {"phone":"(904) 136-2961","name":"Abhi"}
]';
```

I want these two attributes phone and name sent into an iteration in
PHP and store in respective columns like `name` and `phone` in MySQL
using *PHP*

Comment: decode to convert in array and loop through it and store. you should have searched a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Decode the json string using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function and loop through the decoded array using `foreach` loop, like this:

```
$a='[{"phone":"(785) 583-7086","name":"Website 22-2-16"}, {"phone":"(904) 136-2961","name":"Abhi"}]';

$decoded_json = json_decode($a, true);
foreach($decoded_json as $details){
    // phone: $details['phone']
    // name: $details['name']
    // perform your INSERT operation
}
```